# many-to-many relate on two polygon layers in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, relates

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.  (Fairly new to GIS in general!)

I have two polygon shapefiles - school district and council districts - where the polygons overlap irregularly (meaning a school district can intersect with several council districts and vice versa). There is no key field to link them in any way.

I'd like to create a table that relates the two--really for analysis outside of ArcMap.  Someone asked this for QGIS, with some passing references to ArcMap here: [Creating many-to-many table from intersection between two polygon layers in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133467/creating-many-to-many-table-from-intersection-between-two-polygon-layers-in-qgis)

But I'm hoping for some direction on ArcMap.  Seems like it should be doable.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Did you try some of the suggestions in your linked Q&A using the equivalent ArcGIS tools?

Comment: The OP there made reference to relates in ArcMap, which I dismissed.  But looking again, I see that he landed on using Union/Intersect in QGIS.  Will look into the equivalent.  (Missed that!)  I see there are tools with those names in ArcMap as well and will look into whether one of those can help.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have an ArcGIS Desktop Advanced license you could try using the [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) tool.  This tool creates a new table that links two feature classes based on their proximity to each other.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the Intersect tool (similar to the ultimate QGIS answer in the post I linked to).  For those who, like me, appreciate some hand-holding:

1. Opened Intersect tool (ArcToolbox>Analysis Tools>Overlay>Intersect)
2. For Input, selected both polygon shapefiles (left other options as-is); after running, the new feature was added to my map and saved to file
3. Exported data to Excel file (Arctoolbox>Conversion Tools>Table to Excel)
4. For Input, browsed to intersect shapefile created in step 2

Done!  Thanks Midavalo for encouraging proper diligence in investigating ArcMap's version of the QGIS tool.